# Parse Error: unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW => foreach array assignment

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, syntax-error

I am trying to create an associative array that collects the following (existing on the db) information using this code:

```
$pro_xp = array();//array declaration
foreach ($profile_professional_experiences as $each_professional_experience) {
        $pro_xp[] = ('title' => $each_professional_experience->title,
                     'company' => $each_professional_experience->company,
                     'industry' => $eachprofessional_experience->industry,
                     'time_period' => $each_professional_experience->time_period,
                     'duration' => $each_professional_experience->duration);}
```

This current code wins me a Parse Error message, which is not productive for me.  I have seen other assignment questions, but none like this. I'm still new to PHP development, so if this is a rookie mistake, that would be why.

Comment: I think if you look again, you will find you forgot the word `array`...

Comment: I didn't think I needed it since I had declared it above.  I thought I was placing those items into the array at that position. BUT, I have to place an array (with those items) into my original array.

Comment: You still need the `array` keyword. You are creating a sub-array, but it is still a new array. `$var = ('val', 'val');` is not a valid PHP syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($profile_professional_experiences as $each_professional_experience) {
        $pro_xp[] = array('
```

Comment: Thanks.  That got me rolling again.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $pro_xp[] = array('title' => $each_professional_experience->title,
                ^^^^^---add this
```

without the `array` bit, PHP doens't know you want an array. Something like

```
$x = ("Hello");
```

is perfectly valid, but isn't defining an array. It's just a string assignment. Unless you're in an array definition context, the `=>` arrow operator isn't valid.